# Как считывать текст в js введённый в input в html?

Tags: javascript, html

Я хочу, чтобы, при нажатии на кнопку **текст** из **input** записывался в переменную.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите [вот сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1502061/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-js-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0-title-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-div-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4/1502085#1502085)

Comment: Да спасибо именно то что мне нужно